# Angualar 10 : Add descritpion (*d.ts) file manually to compilation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular9, angular-cli-v9

I have a angular library which has the description files *.d.ts. in a below structure

```
├ src
│  ├ my-lib
│  │   ├ my-typedef.d.ts
│  │      
│  │
│  └public_apit.ts
│  
└ tsconfig.lib.json
```

On tsconfig.lib.json i have include it like below:

```
"include": [
    "src/lib/typedefs"
  ],
```

**Edit**

Before upgrading to 10 it was set to angular 8. This files were compiled in the final build package, but after Angular 10. I am facing this issue. though other folders are there but typedefs.

I see on angular upgrade guidelines that we need to add manually but not sure what is the correct way.

> We have updated the tsconfig.app.json to limit the files compiled. If
> you rely on other files being included in the compilation, such as a
> typings.d.ts file, you need to manually add it to the compilation.

https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=8.0-9.0

repo to the issue: https://github.com/amirgc/angular10-ng-build.git

- Download the repo.
- npm install
- ng build

Comment: adding the .d.ts path to tsconfig [types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types) or their containing folder to [typeRoots](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots) help?

Comment: @RazRonen, that is also not working

Comment: how about `src/lib/typedefs/*.d.ts` in the include?

Comment: @RazRonen ,no that also didnt help

Comment: @Amir can you fix the link to the repository you linked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this is the expected behavior as type definitions are not emitted with the upgdrade of [ng-packagr](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr). If we want to emit type description. To emit the .d.ts we can use the assets option, or alternatively change the file to a .ts extensions.
we can add below section on ng-package.json file.

```
{
  "ngPackage": {
    "assets": [
      "CHANGELOG.md",
      "./typedefs/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "lib": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```